# Dynamic list box parameter on jndi datasource in BIRT Report

Tags: jasper-reports, reporting, birt

I made dynamic list box as parameter. if I set data source directly in birt report then list box parameter is coming but if I set the ODA data source on beforOpen event this list box parameter is not working. Please help me. 
.

**- Follwing code on beforeOpen event of datasource

```
var dsName =** reportContext.getHttpServletRequest().getSession().getAttribute("DataSource");
vector = util.getConnection(dsName);
var flag = vector.get(0);

if (flag == '0')
{
    this.setExtensionProperty("odaDriverClass",vector.get(1));
    this.setExtensionProperty("odaURL",vector.get(2));
    this.setExtensionProperty("odaUser",vector.get(3));
    this.setExtensionProperty("odaPassword",vector.get(4));

}
else
{
    this.setExtensionProperty("odaJndiName","java:/"+dsName);
}
```

Note- this ODA data source working in report level but it is not working in parameter level

Comment: Where is this "util" object initialized? *util.getConnection(dsName)*

Comment: I initialize this variable on initialize event of report. Code- var util=0; Actually the problem is-  whats happening here, beforOpen event of data set is not working on parameter level. It is only firing on report level. Can you tell which event will work at parameter level because i have dynamic list box on parameter level and i am reading database schema name from session. thanks in advance.